# is there a global data storage file in the vscode api when generating an extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i am making a vs-code extension in typescript and i need to have some sort of permanent information storage that can be changed. i just have 2 variables i need to access, but i need to be able to boot the extension, change the variables, and then when i reboot the extension the variables are still what i changed them too. i considered just using a file and reading and writing a couple lines of the file, but i figured there was a better way to do it. so do i have to read and write a couple lines of a text file, or is there a permanent variable storage file or some other option that's more convenient?

Comment: use settings, you can update them

Comment: what do you mean @rioV8? sorry I'm not the best with typescript.

Comment: save your persistent variables in `settings` : `contributes.configuration`

Comment: I've done that, but now I'm having trouble figuring out how access those values. `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('extension.property'); returns `Object: object`, and using `const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('extension'); const property = config.get('property');` means `property = '';`@rioV8

Comment: what do you expect to see? Have you read all the API doc of the `Configuration` object. To set initial values use `package.json` or `settings.json`

Comment: i know that. i set them using `"defualt": "hello-world"` in the package.json file and it didnt return anything. @rioV8

Comment: nvm. the default value doesn't seem to want to actually automatically put anything in settings. ill look into it a bit on my own. thanks for the help though

Comment: `"defualt"` is not spelled correct